# Openlayers XYZ not supporting different tileSizes for the same map instance, 512 and 256

Tags: javascript, mapbox, openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-5

1. Using OpenLayers `^7.4.0`
2. Trying to get tiles from 2 different providers one gives 256 tileSize images and the other 512
3. After zoom level 18 or user event, i shift my provider
4. Using new [XYZ](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html) to create the source of each tileLayer

Code for reference:

1. **Tile Layer 1 from first source with 512 tilesize**

```js
const extent = [12445171.1973, -5518141.946, 17346924.9472, -939258.2036];
    const startResolution = getWidth(extent) / 512;
    const resolutions = new Array(20 + 1);
    resolutions[0] = startResolution;
    for (let i = 1, ii = 20; i <= ii; ++i) {
      resolutions[i] = resolutions[i - 1] / 2;
    }

    const mabBox512Source = new XYZ({
      tilePixelRatio: hiDPI ? 2 : 1,
      tileSize: [512, 512],
      tileGrid: new TileGrid({
        extent: extent,
        resolutions: resolutions,
        tileSize: [512, 512],
      }),
      maxZoom: 20,
      tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord) {
        const z = tileCoord[0];
        const x = tileCoord[1];
        const y = tileCoord[2];

        const mapBoxURl = `https://api.mapbox.com/style...............`;

        return mapBoxURl;
      },
    });
    
    const tileLayer1 = new OLTileLayer({
      source: mabBox512Source,
      properties: {
        name: 'BASE_TILE_LAYER_1',
      },
    });
```

2. **Tile Layer 2 from other source with 256 tilesize**

```js
    const startResolution2 = getWidth(extent) / 256;
    const resolutions2 = new Array(20 + 1);
    resolutions2[0] = startResolution2;
    for (let i = 1, ii = 20; i <= ii; ++i) {
      resolutions2[i] = resolutions2[i - 1] / 2;
    }

    const newMap256Source = new XYZ({
      tilePixelRatio: hiDPI ? 2 : 1,
      tileSize: [256, 256],
      tileGrid: new TileGrid({
        extent: extent,
        resolutions: resolutions2,
        tileSize: [256, 256],
      }),
      maxZoom: 20,
      tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord) {
        const z = tileCoord[0];
        const x = tileCoord[1];
        const y = tileCoord[2];

        const nearMapUrl = `https://api.nearmap.com/tiles/.....`;

        return nearMapUrl;
      },
    })
    const tileLayer2 = new OLTileLayer({
      source: newMap256Source,
      properties: {
        name: 'BASE_TILE_LAYER_1',
      },
      visible: false,
    });
```

And on some condition/userAction in a callback function i am doing the below

```js
      console.log("-----------Switch Layer---------");
      tileLayer1.setVisible(false);
      tileLayer3.setVisible(true);
```

**What is going wrong**

***I suspect this is not the right way to do it, as the map stops supporting some configuration rules. Like it is not respecting the maxZoom that i had applied. This is a visible breakage. There is a possibility of other breakages which i might not know.***

Also, i had tried a different way, where i kept a single tileLayer but i switched the source on user Action/conndition(zoom>18), using [setSource](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#setSource).
[image]

Comment: If you replace `tileSize` in the tile grid with a `tileSizes` array you could have all the tiles in a single source (the tileUrlFunction could test the z coordinate to determine which url to return)

Comment: Understood you are recommending to change the url in the tileUrlFunction conditionally(z>=18) so that i can achieve my requirements. But how will openlayers determine which tileSize  to use for a particular tile Provider. How will it know to use 256 or 512. i need a conditional way to handle tileSize as well.

Comment: @Mike can you guid me with the above.

Comment: Something like https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-lgzdwc?file=/main.js 512 pixel osmand tiles are used from level 0 to 9, then 256 pixel OpenStreetmap tiles.  The smaller the tile the more you can fit into the extent, so the z level of 256 pixel tiles is one higher than 512 pixel tiles at the same resolution.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thank you for all help. Really appreciate ur guidance.. One last concern>> When i console the current zoom by map.getView().getZoom() the zoom level is 18.04675686 but the old tileImage is shown. The reason is the tileUrl function is evaluated after zooming in through some threshold. How can i handle that case? Once i zoom through some threshold the tileUrl Funciton is evaluated and this time at 18.563453...something the url for >=18 is considered.

Comment: By default tiles change between zoom levels based on the mean resolution of the two levels - you can change that with the source's  `zDirection` option

Comment: I tried doing so in the XYZ constructor function, but it still does not work. Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.
zDirection: function (value, high, low) {
        return high;
 },

Comment: Use 1 or -1 to change tile zoom immediately before/after an integer view zoom level

Answer (score 0):

With help from [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike) ,
the solution for using two different tileSizes at the same time in the same map instance in openlayers is,

- You XYZ to create the tileSource
- Provide different url's with help from tileUrlFunction
- Also calculate resolutions to provide to the tileGrid option of XYZ.

Read the code snippet below.

```js
const extent = MapService.mapInstance.getView().getProjection().getExtent();
const tileSizes = new Array(20 + 1);
const resolutions = new Array(tileSizes.length);
tileSizes[0] = 512;
resolutions[0] = getWidth(extent) / tileSizes[0];

for (let i = 1, ii = resolutions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  resolutions[i] = resolutions[i - 1] / 2;
  tileSizes[i] = i < 18 ? 512 : 256;
}

const tileSource1 = new XYZ({
  tilePixelRatio: hiDPI ? 2 : 1,
  tileGrid: new TileGrid({
    extent: extent,
    resolutions: resolutions,
    tileSizes: tileSizes,
  }),
  zDirection: -1,
  tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord) {
    let z = tileCoord[0];
    const x = tileCoord[1];
    const y = tileCoord[2];
    const tileSize = tileSizes[z];

    z =
      tileSize > tileSizes[0]
        ? z - 1
        : tileSize < tileSizes[0]
          ? z + 1
          : z;

    const map256URL = `https://map_256images_provider/${z}/${x}/${y}.img?until=1Y&tertiary=satellite&apikey=SOMETHING`;

    const map512URL = `https://map_512images_provider/tiles/512/${z}/${x}/${y}${hiDPI ? '@2x' : ''}?access_token=SOMETHING`;

    const url = tileSize === 512 ? map512URL : map256URL;

    return url;
  },
});

const tileLayer1 = new OLTileLayer({
  source: tileSource1,
  properties: {
    name: 'BASE_TILE_LAYER_1',
  },
});

map.addLayer(tileLayer1);
```